# Migrate to a new Mac does not recognize external HD

Tags: macos, time-machine, osx-mountain-lion, migration-assistant

I bought a new Mac (Mini Late 2012). I have a Time Machine backup of the older computer (Macbook Unibody Late 2008) and I want to restore system configuration and apps. I open Migration Assistant, select Time Machine backup as source of the data but that disk is never recognized, I only see a screen showing "Searching computers".

I have my TM disk connected (it shows in Finder) and the new Mac Mini updated to the latest OSX. I've tried to reboot, CMD+R and select restore from TM but it says that I have to use Migration Assistant because it's another machine's backup.

What can I do?